# Display html return of R function with OpenCPU

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, r, opencpu

I created a R function which produces a data table with rCharts. It looks like this example:
http://rcharts.io/viewer/?7073104#.Uyi3oa15Peg
And the R function returns the table with `return(td2)`. *This should be a html element*

I then want to create a JavaScript function which calls this R function on OpenCPU and displays the returned HTML element in a div. Is used for example the following code to display a returned plot of another function:

```
 $("#submitbutton").click(function(){

    ocpu.seturl("http://public.opencpu.org/ocpu/github/.../R") #shortened
        var key = $("#key").val();  
        var name = $("#name").val();

        var req = $("#plotdiv").rplot("MapInfluencers", {
            username : name,
            api_key : key
        });

        //optional
        req.fail(function(){
            alert("R returned an error: " + req.responseText); 
        });
    });
```

But now I have to display a html element but I can´t find a function in the OpenCPU library which could do this.

Comment: Would it be possible to post an example on `jsfiddle`?

Comment: When it comes to HTML and OpenCPU, I write a function that saves it to file and then add it as the `src` attribute of an iframe in the dom.

Comment: See this app here that uses the approach outlined above. Paste `dTable(mtcars)` in the editor and hit submit. You will see a data table on the right. http://rcharts.io/playground/. Source code for the playground is [here](https://github.com/rcharts/rcharts.github.io/blob/master/playground/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a function `savePlot` that saves the plot in a html file and returns its name.

In your script:

```
var req = ocpu.call(
"savePlot", {
    ......
},
function(session) {
    session.getObject(function(filename) {
        var outputlink = session.getLoc() + "files/" + filename;
        $('#iframe').attr("src", outputlink);
    })
}
);
```

In your body:

```
<iframe id="iframe" width="600" height="300"></iframe>
```